# Different date between sql and view

Tags: sql, laravel, laravel-blade

here is my problem I want to display in my view a date in the format 'Y-d-m H:i:s.u', it is inserted correctly in my database but when it is displayed in the view 2 years were added and days too.[dd of my tickets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RQI9F.png)

In my controller

```
    {
        $tickets = Ticket::where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->paginate(10);
       // dd($tickets);

        return view('tickets.user_tickets', compact('tickets'));
    }
```

In my view
 `<td> {{ $ticket->created_at }}</td>`

Thank you to all those who can help me

Comment: display it using `date` php function `date('F,d Y h:i:s' , strtotime($ticket->created_at))`.

Answer (score 0):

Use PHP `date` function to display in view:

```
date('F,d Y h:i:s' , strtotime($ticket->created_at))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but this did not solve the problem, the date remains 2024-04-01 16:22:22 instead of 2022-04-25 16:22:22.

Answer (score 0):

`$ticket->created_at` *should* be a Carbon instance, meaning you can format it as required via:

```
{{ $ticket->created_at->format('Y-d-m H:i:s.u') }}
```

Check the documentation:

https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-setters

If this doesn't work, make sure your `Ticket.php` model has it specified:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

class Ticket extends Model {
  protected $dates = ['created_at', 'updated_at'];
}
```

Anything in the `protected $dates` can chain the `->format()` method, or any other Carbon method.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but this did not solve the problem, the date remains 2024-04-01 16:22:22 instead of 2022-04-25 16:22:22.

Answer (score 0):

Try it in your view

```
<td>{{ date('Y-d-m H:i:s', strtotime($ticket->created_at)) }}</td>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but this did not solve the problem, the date remains 2024-04-01 16:22:22 instead of 2022-04-25 16:22:22.